# How to Fix Pricing Error in Magento Configurable & Associated Product

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I am trying to fix this Pricing error for all the products:
http://neemafoods.com/grains.html 
http://neemafoods.com/dal-pulses.html

In all these individual products there is a dropdown to select the the Product Weight and depending on that price changes. Here it shows proper price but It shows wrong prices when added to cart.

Magento 1.9 EDO Theme. 3 - 4days back some Malicious code added in Miscellaneous Scripts on theme which puts the AJAX ON by default which has to be OFF but cannot be done off.

How to OFF the AJAX from site and Correct the pricing error?